# Why am I getting errors while downloading virtualenv on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install Open Cv on the raspberry pi. I'm following this tutorial https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/

I ended up getting an error in the middle, I successfully installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper I can see that but when I type the command of profile I get an error saying usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
bash: VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $VIRTUALENV_PYTHON

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo $VIRTUALENV_PYTHON3

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo -e "\n# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper" >> ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs" >> ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source ~/.profile
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
bash: /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat ~/.profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=/home/pi/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=/home/pi/.virtualenvs
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=/home/pi/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nano ~/.profile
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ source ~/.profile
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

How can I fix this problem to proceed download?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the system points at Python2 instead of Python3.
Try opening ~/.profile and point at the specific version like this:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.5
```